# Disk space allocation for a Container and Pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, storage, diskspace

I am aware that we can specify CPU and memory allocation for a Container using [requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) in Kubernetes. But I would like to know how much disk space gets allocated to each container? Also, is there a way to specify this similar to CPU and memory allocation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similarly to the CPU and memory resources, you can use [ephemeral storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#local-ephemeral-storage) to specify disk resources used. Requests and limits can also be use with ephemeral storage.

**Update**:

Please refer to [volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/):

> On-disk files in a Container are ephemeral, which presents some problems for non-trivial applications when running in Containers. First, when a Container crashes, kubelet will restart it, but the files will be lost - the Container starts with a clean state. Second, when running Containers together in a Pod it is often necessary to share files between those Containers. The Kubernetes Volume abstraction solves both of these problems.

You can use one of the different types than  ephemeral-storage,emptydir from volumes to store your data in persistent way.

Comment: I have read about this in the above link but still it's not clear to me. Is this what I am looking for? Also, I read that: On-disk files in a Container are ephemeral i.e., after container restart the files will be lost and the Container starts with a clean state. So does this mean, we shouldn't be using it to store something which we require for longer duration?

Comment: That's correct. This is the writable layer inside containers. Changes made in that layer are lost if you start another container (even if you use the same image).

Comment: Sorry, do you mean this layer contents will be lost after existing container restart?

Comment: @Newbie, pretty sure you have figured this out by now considering I'm replying 3 yrs after but yes anything you write in that container while it's running will all be gone if you're not writing to a volume mount instead.